# d3js alert leaf name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to alert leaf name when click on it, but I don't know how. I am new in D3. How to do that?
Source: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
  .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); else alert(d3.select(this).name); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the line:

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

from CSS section that is defined for `node--leaf`.

This line prevents onclick events from executing, even if you have correct JavaScript code.

Comment: Is it possible to keep text label in leaf? If I remove this line, there are no text in leaf circle. 
Actually onclick I need leaf name to call function: playsound(d.name); so I would like to keep text in leaf.

Comment: In cases like yours (additional questions), encouraged procedure is: Ask another question, and provide relevant code. The pattern of endless additional questions is called "spoon feeding" here, because people behave like babies requesting more and more food, regardless of what and how much one gives them.

Comment: Also, how do you think your question can be answered if you do not show us your code?